# GREP/AWK extract IPv4 or IPv6 from UFW status

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, grep, ufw

How can I extract to a `variable` both the `address (IPv4 or IPv6)` and the `[number]` with `grep` from `ufw status numbered`?

Without using `regex` to find the IP.

```
$ufw status numbered | grep -w 'DNS1'
[277] 53                         ALLOW       216.218.130.2              # DNS1

$ufw status numbered | grep -w 'DNS2'
[288] 53                         ALLOW       2001:470:100::2            # DNS2
```

Comment: can you add the exact output you want? also, if the fields are always the same, `awk` would be better suited

Comment: @Sundeep I want to use it in a bash scrip. So it should assign both the number and the IP to a variable. Regarding the output from `ufw status numbered` is the same. Port number could be different, or ALLOW could be DENY. But they are at the same place in the string.

Comment: In [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218132/grep-awk-extract-ipv4-or-ipv6-from-ufw-status/72218586?noredirect=1#comment127659020_72218586) you left under my question, the input you showed had `ALLOW IN` in the middle, not just `ALLOW`. If the comment was correct then [edit] your question to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cat file` in place of `ufw status numbered` which I don't have:

```
$ portip=( $(cat file | awk -v key='DNS1' '$NF==key{gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1, $4}') )
$ echo "${portip[0]}"
277
$ echo "${portip[1]}"
216.218.130.2
```

Comment: Using awk to filter doesn't return anything. Extracting the data works `awk '{gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1, $5}'`

Comment: As you can see in my answer, when you run the script I provided against the input you provided it produces the output you said you wanted. If it's not doing that for you now then either you copy/pasted it wrong or your real input doesn't look like the example in your question.

Comment: `root@dns:/home/user# ufw status numbered | awk -v key='SSH' '$NF==key{gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1, $5}'
root@dns:/home/user# 
root@dns:/home/user# ufw status numbered | awk -v key='SSH' '$NF==key{gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1, $4}'
root@dns:/home/user# ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 3] 22                         ALLOW IN    2.2.2.2              # SSH
[ 4] 53                         ALLOW IN    1.2.2.3              # PowerDNS`

Comment: This is the output I get. Does not filter. Like this it works: `awk '{gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1, $5}'`

Comment: Then the final string on your target line must not be `SSH`. Check for DOS line endings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-i, as those being present would mean that last input string is `SSH\r` instead of `SSH`. Meanwhile change `$NF==key` to `$NF~key` to do a partial regexp instead of fixed string match on that last field and, whether that works or not, edit your question to show the output of `ufw status numbered | cat -v` so we can see the CRs and LFs so we can provide the best answer for your actual input.