# AWK return/print as associative arrays in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, awk

With this command I am trying to filter through my firewall.
In order to extract the firewall rule ID number and the IP address.

```
existing=($(ufw status numbered | grep -e ''"$ssh_port"'' | grep -i 'SSH' | awk '{gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1 $5}'))
```

The raw output from `ufw status numbered` looks like this:

```
[286] 22                        ALLOW IN    1.1.1.1                    # SSH
[287] 22                        ALLOW IN    1.1.1.1                    # SSH
[299] 22                        ALLOW IN    aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::aaaa  # SSH
```

What I am tying to do is return `print $1 $5` as an array.

In order to access each line in `bash` like this:

```
echo ${existing[0][0]} -> 286
echo ${existing[0][1]} -> 1.1.1.1

echo ${existing[1][0]} -> 287
echo ${existing[1][1]} -> 1.1.1.1

echo ${existing[2][0]} -> 299
echo ${existing[2][1]} -> aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::aaaa
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: bash doesn't have nested or multidimensional arrays, so neither you nor anybody can do this in any way. There are several _other_ forms you could store this data in bash, or you could use something other than bash like awk, perl, python, but it depends on what you want to do. You could however easily have your awk subsume your two grep's.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Was referring to something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468914

Comment: @Nikk, that's a single-dimensional array indexed by strings with commas :)

Comment: @Nikk, that said, why don't you just put two words in your values? `existing[0]='286,1.1.1.1'. Easy enough to use parameter expansion to extract only the piece you want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Because I want to lookup the array like so `if [[ ! "${existing[*]}" =~ "$a" ]];`

Comment: @Nikk, that's not a reasonable way to do a lookup in the first place; serializing the whole array into a single string and doing a regex on it is crazy inefficient.

Comment: @Nikk, ...that said, if you _want_ to do the crazy, inefficient thing, I don't see why the approach I suggested stops you.

Comment: @Nikk, ...but _really_, if you want to do existence checks, the sane way to do them is to have an associative array indexed by the key whose existence you want to check for; that way it's a constant-time lookup instead of getting slower the larger your data is.

Comment: in the case that you could use multi-dim arrays in bash, what would  `${existing[*]}` expand to? `286 1.1.1.1 287 1.1.1.1 ...`?

Comment: You broke [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72218586/1745001) when you removed the `,` after `print $1`. Also, you never need grep when you're using awk. It sounds like you're trying to do too much in shell and should be doing more in awk instead. GNU awk does support true multidimensional arrays by the way.

Comment: @EdMorton The `awk` command doesn't filter the results and returns nothing. The way I ended up using it is `grep` to filter then `awk` to extract the data based on your answer.

Comment: The awk command I provided does exactly what you asked for given the sample input you provided. You never need grep when you're using awk - piping grep to awk is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Simulating the `ufx` output:

```
$ cat ufw.dat
[286] 22                        ALLOW IN    1.1.1.1                    # SSH
[287] 22                        ALLOW IN    1.1.1.1                    # SSH
[299] 22                        ALLOW IN    aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::aaaa  # SSH
```

One idea where we let `awk` pass the desired data to a `bash/while` loop for parsing and storage in a pair of arrays:

```
declare -a id_array=()
declare -a ip_array=()

ndx=-1

while read -r id ip
do
        (( ndx++ ))
        id_array[$ndx]="${id}"
        ip_array[$ndx]="${ip}"

done < <(cat ufw.dat | awk '/SSH/ {gsub(/[][]/,""); print $1,$5}')
```

This generates:

```
$ declare -p id_array ip_array
declare -a id_array=([0]="286" [1]="287" [2]="299")
declare -a ip_array=([0]="1.1.1.1" [1]="1.1.1.1" [2]="aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::aaaa")
```

OP can now use the common index to access both components at the same time, eg,

```
for i in "${!id_array[@]}"
do
    echo "$i : ${id_array[$i]} : ${ip_array[$i]}"
done

0 : 286 : 1.1.1.1
1 : 287 : 1.1.1.1
2 : 299 : aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::aaaa
```